# php email verifier working on localhost, but not working on live server

Tags: javascript, php

```
 [This is my PHP Code.]

            <?php    
            /**
             * Example 1
             * Validate a single Email via SMTP
             */
            // include SMTP Email Validation Class
            require_once('smtp_validateEmail.class.php');

            // the email to validate
            $email = 'user@example.com';
            if($_GET['email'] != '' && isset($_GET['email'])){
                $email = $_GET['email'];
            }
            $port = 25;
            if($_GET['port'] != '' && isset($_GET['port'])){
                $port = $_GET['port'];
            }
            // an optional sender
            $sender = '';
            // instantiate the class
            $SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_validateEmail();
            // turn on debugging if you want to view the SMTP transaction
            $SMTP_Validator->debug = true;
            $SMTP_Validator->port = $port;
            // do the validation
            $results = $SMTP_Validator->validate(array($email), $sender);
            // view results
            echo $email.' is '.($results[$email] ? 'valid' : 'invalid')."\n";
            // send email? 
            if ($results[$email]) {
              //mail($email, 'Confirm Email', 'Please reply to this email to confirm', 'From:'.$sender."\r\n"); // send email
            } else {
              echo 'The email addresses you entered is not valid';
            }
            ?>
```

When I run this script to localhost,then it verify an email accurately,but not working on live server.
[As shown in image email verifier is providing accurate result on localhost.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFod.png)

Comment: What you are try to do? Is this an API call or something else?

Comment: this is simple php script.

Comment: In live server what is the error?

Comment: Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to gmail.com:25 (Connection refused) in /home/content/02/10348302/html/app/emailverify/smtp_validateEmail.class.php on line 154

Error: Could not connect to a valid mail server for this email address: @gmail.com

jagjeet276@gmail.com is invalid The email addresses you entered is not valid

Comment: do you want to check valid email id or not???

Comment: yes,want to check valid email(means: provided email id is currently working or not).

Comment: use normally this thing `if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}` 
`$email` is you email id.

Answer (score 0):

use phpemailer, it will be more useful for u.. download from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

[1](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer): https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ and get example from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)